# Trouble when accessing templated member array

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have a class that allocates a local stack array. This is how it's supposed to be allocated:

```
MyClass<char, 255> my_arr{};
```

This should create a local member that will be `char m_Arr[255]`.

Here is how it is defined:

```
private:
    Type*           m_Buffer[Size];
    unsigned int    m_Size;
```

Here is the class with the constructor:

```
template<class Type, unsigned int Size>
class MyClass {
public:
MyClass() : m_Size{}
{

}
```

**When do the errors happen?**

They happen at compile-time. The functions of my thread are constexpr (It is meant to encrypt the string and offer multiple functions such as splitting, changing to lowercase, allocating more memory in heap if needed, etc.)

**What are the errors?*

Once I add the following operator:

```
operator Type*()
{
    return this->m_Buffer;
}
```

or

```
operator const Type*()
{
    return this->m_Buffer;
}
```

I get the follwing errors:

[image: Error]

Once I remove it, I get the error that the class instance cannot be converted to LPCTSTR (I am passing it to an API that takes that argument type)

If I replace it with the following:

```
Type* Get() {
return this->m_Buffer
}
```

and call it in the API function, all of the errors come back.

**Note:** I tried to create a smaller version of this code, but I cannot recreate it anywhere but my code (300 lines of code). I will try my best to give enough information to 
hopefully fix this issue.

Comment: You say your example declaration should create a `char m_Arr[255]` member, though the class definition you gave has no `m_Arr` member? If `m_Buffer` is supposed to be `m_Arr`, you need to drop the `*`; right now `m_Buffer` is an array of pointers to Type.

Comment: Yes it was a copying error from me. Also I initialize the class `MyClass<char,...>`, making `Type` a `char`, so `Type* Get()` will be `char* Get()`, so nothing is wrong there, no?